# Twitter/Facebook authorization in Windows 8 app with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-runtime, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

Is there any way to login with Facebook/Twitter in Windows 8 app based on Javascript and HTML5?

Authorization pages do not allow themselves to be embedded with `iframe` and I can not navigate topmost window to the authorization url from javascript code ("url because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app.
Visual Studio is not currently attached to a script debug target that supports script diagnostics" error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from one of  Microsoft engineers, thanks him a lot:

There are a couple of ways you can do that.  You can do the work yourself to get the token.  For example ...

https://github.com/cauld/winjs-oauth-for-twitter

... and ...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/1b17ec50-00af-48ff-980c-5bf58145f2a9

Or you can use the WebAuthenticationBroker ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Comment: Actually the first example uses the WebAuthorizationBorker. I forked that project and created a Universal app out of it. Now the same code runs in either Windows or Windows Phone. Check it out: https://github.com/sebagomez/winjs-oauth-for-twitter